# Symfony1 improve AJAX action speed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, symfony-1.4

I have a speed issue with Symfony 1.4 and AJAX.

**My routing:**

```
ajax_search:
      url:   /search.:sf_format
      param: { module: article, action: articlesAjaxSearch, sf_format: html }
      requirements:
        sf_format: (?:html|js)
```

**My js:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  jQuery('#searchform').attr('action'),
    data:  form_data,
    success: function(result)
    {
       jQuery("#searchform #searchresult").html(result).slideDown('fast');
    }
});
```

My action:

```
public function executeArticlesAjaxSearch(sfWebRequest $request) { 
          $this->getResponse()->setContent("<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>");

            return sfView::NONE;

    }
```

This is a shorter version, but I need to improve speed. The AJAX call need around 200 ms to fetch this HTML content back.

Here's my log:

```
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {articleActions} Call "articleActions->executeArticlesAjaxSearch()"
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send status "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Configuration 0.88 ms (8)
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Factories 53.19 ms (1)
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Action "article/articlesAjaxSearch" 115.39 ms (1)
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Database (Doctrine) 0.01 ms (3)
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} View "None" for "article/articlesAjaxSearch" 0.00 ms (1)
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebResponse} Send content (39 o)
```

I need a solution to improve my ajax request speed for symfony 1

```
Sep 05 09:25:58 symfony [info] {sfWebDebugLogger} Action "article/articlesAjaxSearch" 115.39 ms (1)
```

I don’t understand why this take so long. Hope anyone can help me out I searching for more then one day for a solution.

The whole time of the ajax request take ~200ms without implement logic.

Comment: Try turning off your `sfWebDebugLogger` for this action, it will slow things down a lot. If you still wish to see timings, implement your own using `microtime()` and return it with your AJAX response. Of course, if you just want hello world, implement it using an ordinary PHP file, and skip symfony entirely.

Comment: Cant disable webdebuglogger, but i tried it too in prod env out and nothing speed is better.

Comment: I need to find out to make a new factories with defaults for a module.
But he still get inherited properties... from application factories.yml
Anyone know how to override for a module a factorie with default settings?

Comment: "Cant disable webdebuglogger" - do you mean "won't"? It is entirely possible to turn off the debug toolbar.

Comment: I mean, i tried it so set in settings off and in factories. But it dont work.
I have a module with a factories.yml in a application. Maybe the factories.yml from the application will load in this case?

Comment: In earlier versions, it can be switched dynamically in your action using `sfConfig::set('sf_debug', false);`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just:

```
public function executeArticlesAjaxSearch(sfWebRequest $request) {
  // ...
  echo json_encode($answer);
  exit;
}
```

You can put the module into separate application and disable unneeded [filters](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/12-Filters). You can also use separate enviroment and disable, or use faster implementation for [factories](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/05-Factories).

Comment: This workds nicely :) thx
Could you write a facotries.yml that remove all overhead?
I have removed something but there is still 45ms left :/

Comment: It's about features you need from that factory. For example sfPatternRouting is quite expensive, you can use class sfNoRouting, I think this requires changing the urls. Or you can write your own. Then you can use sfNoLogger for logger entry.

Comment: To clarify, factory setting is just an entry in a configuration array, nothing is loaded unless you ask for it.

Comment: i dont get where the factories loaded by. I throw a exception at the start of the action.
Maybe he loads from the application the factories? i created a module with a config folder and a new factories.yml in there.
All changes dont work imo.

Comment: i found out that factories.yml in a module dont work http://symfonyexperts.com/question/show/id/13

Comment: You got me lost. What are you trying to do? The link is about factories in plugins, you certainly don't want to go this way.

Comment: Factories in modules don't work, that's why I suggested new enviroment. You are not limited to prod, dev, test.

Comment: dont find to switch env in action for this request

Comment: It's not possible to switch, it's defined from the very beginning of the request. Creation is described here: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/21?orm=Doctrine

Comment: yes but then i dont understand.. you said i should make a new enviroment. I need too be in prod enviorent, if i make the request i have to switch to another or i'm thinking wrong?

Comment: Basicly you copy all prod configuration to this new enviroment, and change only what you want. It's not possible to "extend" another enviroment, only the 'all' section is common. Where the settings are the same, it will be the same.

Comment: Application wide, only app.yml, factories.yml, and settings.yml are enviroment aware, so in these copy 'prod' section under new name, and change whatever you need.